# Fedora Linux: Way to use stty (or equivalent) to bind key to raise SIGUSR1 for application?

Tags: linux, signal, fedora, linux-device-driver

I'm using FC 14, but this is probably a fairly generic Linux question.

I want to be able to bind a key in the Linux terminal driver that will cause a signal other than `SIGINT` or `SIGQUIT` to be raised for the running application.  I don't want to co-opt either of those.  If it rings a bell for you, think along the lines of the old `CTRL/T` capability, only with the signal being caught and handled by the app rather than the OS.

Since this is for status reporting for long-running activities, `SIGUSR1` seems appropriate.  However, if specifically raising that from the terminal keyboard isn't an option, I'll take what I can get.  I don't want to attempt the impossible and catch `SIGKILL` B-) but I *would* like to be able to raise signals other than `SIGQUIT` and `SIGINT` from the terminal keyboard.

Scenario:

1. Set up the terminal to do the signal-raising thing
2. Run application from shell in terminal window
3. Wait until it gets into the complex long-running section
4. Press `CTRL/whatzit` to raise the signal
5. Application catches the signal, does some sort of status report, and resumes

I could do this with no problems on VMS/OpenVMS, and it kinda frosts my pumpkins to think it's more difficult on Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The interface for raising signals via magic characters is, unfortunately, not a generic bind-character-to-signal thing - there are certain specific signals which can be raised like this, and you get to choose the character, but not the signal: see [the relevant chapter of the POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap11.html).

(Apart from `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT`, your other option for co-opting a signal is `SIGTSTP`, if you can live without being able to stop your process with `^Z` - which I guess might be the case if you're expecting to leave it running in the foreground anyway.)

Comment: That's what I feared.  Thanks for the pointer and the answer!